# Soul vs spirit in a specific sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Do the following self-made sentences mean the same:

> - May his soul rest in peace! I am sure that his **soul** has now reached heaven.
> - May his soul rest in peace! I am sure that his **spirit** has now reached heaven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diction-wise, both sentences mean the same thing, however in America it is more common to omit reference to the soul and simply say something like

> May he rest in peace.

or

> I'm cetain he's happy in heaven. / At least he's resting in heaven now.

If both the speaker and griever are strong Christians, perhaps

> I bet he's having plenty of fun in heaven right now.

If the griever is antagonisticly atheist (i.e. the type of person who scoffs at Christianity and is quite pretentious), anything more than "rest in peace" ***will*** be taken as an insult.

If the griever is agnostic, a tolerant atheist, an "Easter & Christmas" Christian, or of most any other religion, a passing reference to heaven is fine, but it would be inconsiderate to go as far as to say "he's having fun"

As to Southerners: Most people in the south are of the "Easter & Christmas" variety. This means that they identify as Christian, and they go to church on Easter and Christmas, but they aren't strong Christians that necessarily go to church every Sunday, or if they do they see church as more of a chore than anything else.

Comment: I don't think "Easter & Christmas" is quite true everywhere in The South. I spend quite a bit of time in Nashville, have family there. Many, many churches there, packed every Sunday. Bible studies during the week, etc. Southern Baptist thinking is everywhere.

Comment: @djna In my experience living in VA for six years, while I agree that church attendance is much higher in the 'bible belt' than other places in America, I believe that at least a plurality of people can be categorised as "not maintaining a focus on Christ as an integral part of their lives"

Comment: Agreed, that's a fair summary.

Answer (score 0):

Informally we do tend to use **soul** and **spirit** interchangeably, but different religions have quite technical meanings of these words.

Even more technically **Rest In Peace** may not apply to souls, and might conflict with the spirit being in heaven.

Some people believe (or in the past some people believed) that it was the body that is Resting In Peace while the spirit is in heaven and the two will be reunited in the future, after resurrection.

Others believe that the person (soul) is now at rest, in the grave, eternal sleep, no heaven.

There are many other beliefs about hat happens to spirits and souls after death.
Personally, I would have no wish to enter this mine-field of belief systems; the chances of your getting it right from a particular believer's perspective are pretty slim! I would focus on those left behind and sympathise with their feelings

> I'm sorry for your loss.

is a common starting point.

Comment: Thank you @djna, but irrespective of what is the second person's belief and religion, which one of the above sentences would be heard mostly in US? I know that the southern AE people are mostly very religious and have strong belief in these matters; then which one of these two words would be heard in this sense and which one is the most idiomatic and natural which would not seem to be strange to be heard among American southern people? I usually hear / read people use 'soul'; do you confirm it too?

Comment: Neither sentence would be heard in the US because your phrasing "soul/spirit has now reached heaven" is not how people speak, and we would not combine with RIP. In my experience "**soul** is more usually used than **spirit** in USA and UK, but there are big variations between say Southern Baptists and Roman Catholics (different Christian groups in the US) as to their choice of words and technical phrasing. You would not say the same thing to a Baptist as you would say to a Catholic. Honestly, although you are right that there is strong belief, the details are very variable.

Comment: Just to elaborate: you can't speak of these things independently of the details of people's beliefs.

Comment: I think you are being too subtle. [This list of condolence messages](http://www.quickcondolence.com/200-condolence-examples) includes 5 which use "soul rest (in peace)" It clearly has currency among native speakers. The second example, using spirit, is better as it avoids the repetition of "soul". Though I do think that simpler is better, and "I'm sorry for your loss" is a good way to start.

Comment: Yes Rest In Peace has currency, but with whom? The religious or the non religious? The questioner seems to be most interested in the views of the religious. The second part "spirit has reached heaven" is very much not a phrase that would be used in any Christian circle that I know, I think it's from a different tradition. Together the two phrases really don't fit. Honestly, this is a delicate area, I would err on the side of saying as little as possible, unless you are fluent in the particular set of religious sensibilities.